# How to store JSON response into NSPredicate using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, core-data

1. I need to pass values in first cell using another view controller
2. I need to check whether that exists by using NSPredicate
3. If it's then I need reload data

Please help me first How to store my JSON into NSPredicate. Others I can do!

My JSON :

```
RESULT :(
          {
             A01 =    (
                         {

                           name = "Nano";
                           day  = "monday";

                        },
                        {
                           name = "Nano";
                           day  = "sunday";
                        },
                     );

             A02 =   (
                        {
                           name = "Nano";
                           day  = "wednesday";
                        },
                        {
                           name = "Nano";
                           day  = "tuesday";
                        },
                    );
            }
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to I'm writing it as steps

1. you need to pass values in first cell using segues
2. you can check whether that exists by using NSPredicate
3. If it's then you can reload data

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I am new for this. I like it so much your the way of steps regarding my question. Thank you Misha. I will change my question.

Comment: @MrDoubt glad to hear :D you  can google each of these , you might get your answer

Comment: Please delete your post now If u dont mind. I am searching answers.

Comment: just a suggestion maybe u should ask another question and you can't store json into NSPredicate. You can use NSPredicate to search from core Data

Comment: give some ideas please. I am already storing some values into NSPredicate different arttributes. Now above JSON making tenison. I am trying offline storage process. So I am parsing all data's and storing into locally. then am loading on tableview.Now what is the solution for above process.

Comment: I think you should read a bit about NSPredicate. NSpredicate just fetches data according to your requirment

Answer (score 0):

use below code to store json in NSPredicate and do some filtering whatever you want..

```
NSString *str = @"name";
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] %@",str];
     json = [[json filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
     NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

Comment: yes MrDoubt its array of mutable type and please do not forgot to check mark if this code helps you.

Comment: Its making crash on line 3 of ur code buddy! -[__NSCFDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a0f1f90

Comment: first tell me what you are going to store in json from above json response so ill help you in batter way

Comment: Above mentioned JSON response completely I want to store. Its possible?

Comment: yes MrDoubt i have just edit code just check it first and tell me have you got any error ?